# What does :: mean in Ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby

What is `::`?

```
@song ||= ::TwelveDaysSong.new
```

Comment: I knew about namespace, but I had not seen :: used without a prefix. I guess that was what confused me. I understand now that it refer's to the root level Object namespace

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Ruby :: (double semi colons)**

Top level constants are referenced by double colons

```
class TwelveDaysSong
end

a = TwelveDaysSong.new
#I could wrote it like this too
a = ::TwelveDaysSong.new 

module Twelve
  class TwelveDaysSongs
  end
end

b = Twelve::TwelveDaysSong.new
#b is not equal to 
a = ::TwelveDaysSong.new
#neither
a = TwelveDaysSong.new
```

Classes are constant too so if you have a constant

```
HELLOWOLRD = 'hw'
```

you could call it like this `::HELLOWORLD`

Answer (score 3):

This is a method of lazily initializing the `@song` instance variable.

If `@song` is already set (to some truthy value, that is, not `nil` or `false`), then the expression just evaluates to that value.

If, however, `@song` is not already set to such a value, then it creates a new instance of the class `TwelveDaysSong` and assigns it to `@song`.  Then, as before, the expression evaluates to the value of `@song`, but that value is now a reference to the newly-created `TwelveDaysSong` object.

The use of `::` on the class name means that it is an absolute, top-level class; it will use the top-level class even if there is also a `TwelveDaysSong` class defined in whatever the current module is.

Answer (score 0):

Return `@song`

If `@song` is false (for instance it doesn't exist)
create a new instance of the `::TwelveDaysSong` object as @song